# Wordlike Input screen in website (docs.google or hotmail) javascript php

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea, word-processor

I believe the title already says it all, but here is my question:

what I want to know is how to realize a Office Wordlike "piece of paper" inputscreen. 
I want to build a some kind of "newsletter renderer" which I want to show such an screen for the user.
only solution I could think of was an big `<textarea>` with some CSS styling.

(I already searched on the web but I still found nothing)
Excuse my writing, I'm not so great in English.

---

I have used the JavaScript-based "WYSIWYG editor" now. It 'works' , but for my own emailing backend (to come) I need to get the value out of there Iframe.

id of iframe is: #content_ifr .
in the iframe (what i've found) there is a < p > element where my/your submitted text is put in.

But if I put the following code in console, I get "an empty string" back:
console.debug($("#content_ifr").contents().find("p").contents().val());

or "undefined" :

console.debug($("#content_ifr").contents().find("p").contents().value);

what to do? :O

I will put latest version online asap: http://dominiquedebrabander.nl/nieuwsbrief

---

update: 
console.debug(tinyMCE.get('content').startContent) is the way to get the content out of the iframe. (is it?) thanks (2 thirtydot ;))

I think i'm helped here, but I have 1 small question left (just because I am curious), how do they get the selected text? (to achieve underlines and bold on selected text).
"window.getSelection()" doesn't seem to work? or am I doing something wrong? :O

Comment: This is a really broad question. What have you tried so far? What *specifically* are you having problems with?

Comment: dominiquedebrabander.nl/nieuwsbrief is what I started building, I think you will see immediately what I want.

Comment: Regarding your update, check out the code here: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/ajax_load_save.php. `var ed = tinyMCE.get('content');` is the magical line you need to `"get the value out of there Iframe"`.

Comment: For your update update, take a look at the fancy view source [here](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/jquery_plugin.php), at the end labelled `<!-- Some integration calls -->`. If you have more queries, you need to ask a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what I want to know is how to realize a Office Wordlike "piece of paper" inputscreen

It sounds like you're looking for a JavaScript-based "WYSIWYG editor".

Try [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/), here's a relevant [demo](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php).

Comment: yes I was searching to something like that, but my question was really how to realize something like that to yourself?

Comment: How to make your own 'JavaScript-based "WYSIWYG editor"'? That's not really a good option, it's similar to "writing your own jQuery" - in a word: foolish. What you should do is customize an *existing editor* to behave as you want. If you *really* want to make your own, I suggest you take a look at the source code of existing editors - they're all written in JavaScript, after all.

Comment: I have used the editor provided in the answer of 'thirtydot' ;)